# How to assign a user to an Azure Resource Group

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a new Resource Group, a new Active Directory User and then assign the User to the Resource Group as a Contributor.

So far I have used the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager` to create the Resource Group successfully and the AD User with the `Microsoft.Graph`. I can see both in Azure and can access them both.

However, I can't find clearly how to assign the user to the resource group with C# in either the Resource Manager or Graph API.

I can see how to do it in everything else here > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

I have taken that as being the Graph API call graphClient.DeviceManagement.RoleAssignments
However, from the properties I can't clearly see where I put the Resource Group details.

This is my attempt below, but I get an error:
*Request not applicable to target tenant*

```
var roleAssignment = await graphClient.DeviceManagement.RoleAssignments.Request().AddAsync(new DeviceAndAppManagementRoleAssignment
                {
                    DisplayName = "Test Role",
                    Members = new List<string>
                    {
                        createdUser.Id // GUID of new User
                    },
                    ResourceScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "/subscriptions/04cbb440-e619-4c8f-869f-8dc4d7dd6e42/resourceGroups/NewResourceGroup" // ID of Resource Group
                    },
                    RoleDefinition = new RoleDefinition
                    {
                        RolePermissions = new List<RolePermission> {

                            new RolePermission {
                                ResourceActions = new List<ResourceAction>
                                {
                                    new ResourceAction {
                                        AllowedResourceActions = new List<string> {"*"},
                                        NotAllowedResourceActions = new List<string>
                                        {
                                            "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Delete",
                                            "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
                                            "Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action"
                                        }
                                      }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Can someone either tell me how I can easliy do this or where to look?

Comment: You should use Azure management REST API instead of Microsoft Graph API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest

Comment: @TonyJu I see that could be an option, but why can't I use the Graph SDK?

Comment: The RBAC Graph API is for Intune requires an active Intune license for the tenant. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-rbac-deviceandappmanagementroledefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @TonyJu ok, thank you. I will work on that as a solution, but I will leave the question open as I would still like to know how you would use the Graph API to do this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we should use [Azure management REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest) to to manage access to **Azure resources**.

The [RBAC Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-rbac-deviceandappmanagementroledefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0) is for **Intune** requires an **active Intune license** for the tenant. It manages the role based access in Intune.

Comment: What I am looking for is a method to do this through the SDK instead of the API.